# Accessing property of Controller class from another class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, constructor, properties

My code might be bit lengthy but easy to understand as I have tried my best to explain it, so please bare with me.
I have a controller class as:

```
public class QueryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<QueryController> log;
        public bool ISReadCol { get; set; } //Focus on this part

        public QueryController(ILogger<QueryController> logger)
        {
            this.log = logger;           
        }
        
        [HttpGet("/api/v2/{database}/Tables/{table}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetColFields(
             [FromRoute] string database,
             [FromRoute] string table,
             CancellationToken cancel)
        {
            //some code

            ISReadCol = true;   //setting property to true    
            return await GetQueryResult(database);          
        }        
        
         private async Task<IActionResult> GetQueryResult(string database)
        {
           //some code
           
           return new QueryResult(pool, log);  //[1]
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to access the property "ISReadCol" in the "QueryResult" class.

The "QueryResult.cs" is as follows:

```
class QueryResult : ActionResult
    {
        private readonly ILogger log;
        private readonly ConnectionPoolEntry poolEntry;
        
        public QueryResult(ConnectionPoolEntry poolEntry, ILogger log)
        {           
            this.log = log;            
            this.poolEntry = poolEntry;            
        }
        
        public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
        {   
            **//HOW CAN I ACCESS THE "ISReadCol" property here???.** 
        }
    }
```

IF I pass "QueryController" instance in "QueryResult" constructor such as:

```
private readonly QueryController QR;

public QueryResult(ConnectionPoolEntry poolEntry, ILogger log, QueryController QR)
{           
    this.log = log;            
    this.poolEntry = poolEntry;   
    this.QR = QR;           
}
    and then QR.ISReadCol, but that doesn't work too as [1] call need to be updated too.
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the ISReadCol value as parameter ?

Comment: Controller shouldn't contain properties. They should be stateless. They definitely shouldn't have other classes accessing properties in them. You need to rethink your design and come up with a more functional approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just passed 'ISReadCol' as argument and modified the function calls accordingly